# Update one Pmw control using value from another within the same class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a Pmw (http://pmw.sourceforge.net) plugin for PyMOL (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymol/), but I just cannot update the value of a `Pmw.ComboBox` using changes made to a `Pmw.RadioSelect` control.

The error I keep getting is:

```
    File "/Users/x/.pymol/plugins/mymixer.py", line 82, in sdqRadioChanged
    self.scheme_listing._list.setlist(scList)
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: MyMixer instance has no attribute 'scheme_listing'
```

This appears to be a mistake in scope, but I have no idea how to re-architect the entire plugin to be able to access the `scheme_listing` attribute of a `MyMixer` instance. Similar examples for python/Pmw/tkinter, on the web, appear to work fine (or so it appears to me with my limited understanding of python GUI programming).

Attached below is a MWE that runs (and fails) from within PyMOL (shows up in the menu under Plugins > MyMixer). Note: If you run this on OSX, make sure you are running PyMOLX11Hybrid.app

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# ==========================
# IMPORTS
# ==========================

import Pmw

# ==========================
#  MAIN CLASS
# ==========================

class MyMixer():

    colbrew = {'color':{'red': ['apple', 'strawberry', 'carrot'],
                    'blue': ['blueberry', 'smurfberry', 'icee'],
                    'green': ['spinach', 'chilli', 'lettuce']},
               'shape':{'round': ['baseball', 'basketball', 'golfball'],
                    'oblong': ['football', 'shoes', 'eggs'],
                    'square': ['box', 'laptop', 'yourhead']}}

    def __init__(self, app):

        parent = app.root
        self.parent = parent
        self.dialog = Pmw.Dialog(parent, buttons=('Exit', ),
                             title='MyMixer Plugin',
                             command=self.button_pressed)
        self.dialog.geometry('650x780')
        self.dialog.bind('<Return>', self.button_pressed)

        # -- Initialize main notebook
        self.notebook = Pmw.NoteBook(self.dialog.interior())
        self.notebook.pack(fill='both', expand=1, padx=3, pady=3)

        self.sdq_radio = Pmw.RadioSelect(self.dialog.interior(),
                                     selectmode='single',
                                     buttontype='radiobutton',
                                     labelpos='nw',
                                     label_text='Colbrew Style:',
                                     label_font='inconsolata 16',
                                     orient='horizontal',
                                     frame_relief='ridge',
                                     command=self.sdqRadioChanged)

        self.sdq_radio.pack(padx=0, anchor='n')

        schemeStyleTypes = self.colbrew.keys()

        for item in schemeStyleTypes:
            self.sdq_radio.add(item, font='inconsolata 16')

        self.sdq_radio.invoke(0)

        scListItems = self.colbrew.get(self.sdq_radio.getvalue())

        self.scheme_listing = Pmw.ComboBox(self.dialog.interior(),
                                    scrolledlist_items=scListItems,
                                    labelpos='nw',
                                    label_text='Scheme Name:',
                                    label_font='inconsolata 16',
                                    listbox_height=10,
                                    entry_width=3,
                                    selectioncommand=self.schemeListCommand,
                                    dropdown=True)

        self.scheme_listing.pack(padx=20, pady=2, anchor='e')

        # -- Reflow notebook

        self.notebook.setnaturalsize()

        # -- Show the main dialog

        self.dialog.show()

    def schemeListCommand(self, value):
        print value

    def sdqRadioChanged(self, value):
        scList = self.colbrew.get(value)
        self.scheme_listing._list.setlist(scList) # THIS IS THE POINT OF FAILURE !!!
        print value

    # -- Utility function for button controls

    def button_pressed(self, result):
        if result == 'Exit' or result is None:
           self.dialog.withdraw()

# ==========================
#  PLUGIN INITIALIZATION
# ==========================

def __init__(self, *args):
    self.menuBar.addmenuitem('Plugin', 'command', 'Start MyMixer',
                         label='MyMixer',
                         command=lambda s=self: MyMixer(s))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `self.sdq_radio.invoke(0)` prior to the statement where you define `self.scheme_listing`. When you call that `invoke` method, it is trying to access that variable before it is set. You should set the variable before calling the invoke method.

Comment: Holy Crap! You are absolutely right! I guess my _thinking_ was way too object-oriented and not procedural enough!!! (Sorry, can't upvote you yet, don't have enough internet points!)